# Where to find the syscall_64.tbl in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls, x86

I was following this guide to add my own custom system call inside the Linux kernel "[Adding a Hello World System Call to Linux Kernel](https://medium.com/anubhav-shrimal/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-dad32875872)".

In Step 5, it asks to modify the system call table by going into

> /usr/src/linux-headers-x.x.x-xx/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/

I looked into my system with OS version- Ubuntu 20.04.1 and then kernel version 5.4.0-42, but the specific directory had only three files

> `Makefile`   `syscallhdr.sh`   `syscalltbl.sh`

I searched online and found that the newer versions of Linux use this bash script `syscalltbl.sh` to generate the desired file containing all system call numbers. So thought of running this file, but couldn't due to permission issues(I am newbie in Linux, so didn't found it a good idea to touch things much).

Then I searched for another guide, since the the guide I mentioned above was about 2 years old, and so found this video tutorial created just 4 months back, "[Add your own system call to Linux Kernel](https://youtu.be/6NI1w3DcL7Q)".

In this the guy uses the already present `syscall_64.tbl` file (the `.sh` file is too present), so I thought this might be some problem with my machine only as the "[Official GitHub Repository](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls)" also contains the `.tbl` file along with bash script.

I upgraded my kernel to the latest version 5.9.0-050900-generic, but still the directory

> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900/arch/x86/entry/syscalls

has only the bash files with the Makefile.

So where exactly can I find the `syscall_64.tbl` in my system?

The only thing which comes to my mind is creating `syscall_64.tbl` myself in the the mentioned directory using the `syscall_64.tbl` file available on the [GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl). But I believe this is a not good idea, there might be risks associated with it, which I have no clue.

Comment: I have tried looking for syscall_64.tbl, using "whereis syscall_64.tbl" command, but it just prints "syscall_64:", nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is in the source code for the Linux kernel. You can grab a tarball for the latest release from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

If you want to play around with modifying the Linux kernel, I would do so by building a new kernel (separate from your main system) and running it in a virtual machine like QEMU. You can find various guides on the internet like ["Build and run minimal Linux / Busybox systems in Qemu"](https://gist.github.com/chrisdone/02e165a0004be33734ac2334f215380e) that show you how to get a little development environment up and running.

Comment: I guess you have answered just based on the question title and not the text provided. I already did upgrade to the latest kernel, but I am not able to find the file in the folder, where it usually lies.

Comment: That's because when you install a kernel package on a binary distro like Debian or Fedora, you don't get the sources. Just the binaries (that go in `/boot`), and maybe the headers if you've installed some external modules.

Comment: So I should upgrade my kernel again using the link you have provided? But, I am not sure how to proceed, could you mention the terminal commands I should use for the purpose? Also, it would be nice if you add your reply in the answer itself.

Comment: @deadLock I reject your edit, please, make an answer of your own.